# Oracle UPDATE /*+append*/ ROW MOVEMENT

Tags: oracle, sql-update, append

I have a table partitioned according to **valid_to_date** in Oracle 18. Row movement enabled.

I **UPDATE** the **valid_to_date** column so that it moves from one partition to another one.
I suppose, Oracle does internally something like DELETE in one partition and INSERT into another partition.

Does it something like normal **INSERT** or **INSERT /* +append */**

Because I know **/* + append */** is kind of more efficient...

Comment: You'd have to ask Oracle that question, since you're asking about how the internal code works.Have you tried testing? Also insert append isn't necessarily efficient, since (for example) by adding rows to above the high water mark, it doesn't make best use of the space that might otherwise be available to it, so it's not efficient in terms of space.

Comment: I meant efficient in terms of speed, not space.

Comment: and if I insert without append hint into compressed partition, it will not compress?

Answer (score 1):

Row movement does not use append hint, and no, unless you're updating a lot of rows, it is NOT more efficient than a simple insert. One simple reason It can't be used is that after such an insert, you cannot use the table unless you commit/rollback. So, if Oracle does APPEND under the hood, it will probably break your code.

Answer (score 0):

It will necessarily consume processing resources on your machine while running (it will read the table, it will delete/insert the rows at the bottom of the table to move them up, it will generate redo, it will generate undo).

[see Asktom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:35203106066718)

The "insert the rows at the bottom of the table" clause most probably means using the append hint